# I stupidly tar a .tex file twice and become binary, any chance to save it back?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, latex, tar

My tex file used to be utf-8.
When I tried to compress it to send to others, I accidentally tar the file twice using 

`tar -xf litreview.tex figure/
tar -cf litreview.tex figure/`

(figure/ is the directory where I store my figs for the .tex)

and my .tex became a binary file 

`Master:LitReview ning$ file litreview.tex
litreview.tex: POSIX tar archive`

When I tried to untar it, I received

`Master:LitReview ning$ tar -xvf litreview.tex
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...`

Any chance to convert it back to tex?

Comment: You've pretty much overwritten your original file with whatever the tar'ed version of `figure/` is.

Comment: So are there any chance to change it back?

Comment: Very unlikely. I'd say the only chance is if the file was in the direction `figure/` already, because then it would be part of the `tar` file. But in that case, there wouldn't be a problem, since you would have an unmodified copy already.